Mypy error: PEP 695 type aliases are not yet supported
I encountered an error while trying to use type aliases in Python with MyPy. Here's a simplified version of my code:
type IntList = list[int]  # This line causes the error

type OtherType = int      # This line causes the error

class test:
    pass

type SomeType = test      # This line causes the error


I'm using Python 3.12, which supposedly supports PEP 695 type aliases. Am I doing something wrong, missing an import, or is Mypy's support for PEP 695 incomplete?

Edit:
Looks like I get no errors from MyPy if I am doing it this way.
IntList: TypeAlias = list[int]

OtherType: TypeAlias = int

class test:
    pass

SomeType: TypeAlias = test


Edit:
How do you alias a type in Python?
Is this because of the option in Python 3.9+?

"[...] is Mypy's support for PEP 695 incomplete?": Yes. You will either have to wait (FYI, it only added support for match statements about a year after 3.10 is released), or switch to Pyright/another type checker.

I switched to Pyright and seems to work fine.
I can even say
class test(ABC):
something: TypeAlias

Update (October 2024): mypy 1.12 has just been released with full support for PEP 695, enabled by default (no experimental flag is needed anymore).
Update (July 2024): mypy 1.11 has just been released, with support for almost all of PEP 695 (all the code in the question checks, in particular). This is a large release, so (as the new warning will tell you) the support only works with
--enable-incomplete-feature=NewGenericSyntax on the command line or enable_incomplete_feature = "NewGenericSyntax" in a configuration file (e.g. under [tool.mypy] in pyproject.toml).
The few not-yet-supported parts of PEP 695 are tracked and detailed in this issue. Currently it's only:

some interactions with :=, yield, await,
the infer_variance argument to TypeVar,
any bugs that are likely to arise (it's a big feature).

Original answer: PEP 695 (the new generics syntax) is not implemented in mypy≤1.10 yet (as the error message tries to say), the issue tracking that is here:
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15238
So you can use type x = y in Python 3.12 and the interpreter will work, but checking types with mypy≤1.10 won't.
Note that even after it's implemented in the latest mypy, it likely won't ever be supported by mypy running on Python ≤3.11. So this alias syntax won't be used in any place that commits to support 3.11.
Backwards-compatible code needs to use older style or TypeAliasType (supported in mypy since 1.10).

But I don't undersand, according to release notes 1.10.0 https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2024/04/mypy-110-released.html is supported. Whay am I missing ?

I've updated the answer. Mypy 1.10 adds support for TypeAliasType but not for the 'type' keyword. Mypy 1.11 will most probably have the 'type' keyword with most of it features, though not all.

Worchna, actually --enable-incomplete-feature=NewGenericSyntax is need in 1.11.0+dev and it solves my issues. Thanks

enable_incomplete_feature doesn't seem to be an option under [tool.mypy] in pyproject.toml, according to the linked config file docs.

@DSteman It works with quotes in pyproject.toml (I edited my answer to fix this). It also work as [mypy] followed by enable_incomplete_feature=NewGenericSyntax in either mypy.ini or setup.cfg. I should have checked with mypy --no-incremental  . to not rely on cache. The documentation indeed only lists the command line arg, but I believe the options are almost the same everywhere. It was mentioned in the release notes.
